# Using a variable of a .swift file in another .swift file of same project

Tags: swift

I want to use the value variable **AlarmValInt**  in **AlarmViewController**. Below is a small portion of

**AlarmViewController.swift**:

```
class AlarmViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var AlarmTextField: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var AlarmLabel: UILabel!

    @IBAction func AlarmOK(sender: AnyObject) {
        let AlarmValFloat:Float = NSString(string: AlarmTextField.text).floatValue
        let AlarmValInt:Int = NSString(string: AlarmTextField.text).integerValue
        var AlarmValDec:Float = AlarmValFloat - Float(AlarmValInt)
        var AlarmValSec = AlarmValDec*100
        //println("\(AlarmValSec),\(AlarmValDec*100)")
        if (AlarmValFloat <= 10) {
            AlarmLabel.text = "H2S Alarm level = \(AlarmValInt)min:\(AlarmValSec)sec"
        }
        else {
            AlarmLabel.text = "Invalid time. Enter <= 10"
        }
        self.AlarmTextField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
```

and I want to "append" the value of **AlarmValInt** to an array **graphPoints** in **GraphView.swift**. A small portion (starting few lines) of this file:

**GraphView.swift**

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class GraphView: UIView {

  //Weekly sample data
  var graphPoints:[Int] = [4, 2, 6, 4, 5, 10, 3]
  //var graphPoints:[Int] = [0] 
  //graphPoints.append(AlarmViewController.AlarmOK.AlarmValInt) //Not surprised this did not work
```

How can I use the variable value from first file and append that value to an array in second file?

**ANS**: I am assuming someone might have same question at some point so the way I solved it is: in **AlarmViewController.swift**: `graphView.graphPoints.append(8)//8 is appended to the array graphPoints`

NOTE: graphView is the subview of a another view in AlarmViewController view

Comment: Please don't capitalize all (...any...) of your variable names.

Answer (score 3):

You've declared `AlarmValInt` as a local variable inside your `AlarmOK` method. Declare it as an instance variable (outside of the method, where the `@IBOutlets` are declared). You then need to instantiate an instance of your `AlarmViewController` class. Assuming you've called this `alarm`:

```
graphPoints += alarm.AlarmValInt
```

Of course, if you're using AlarmValInt as a constant (declared using `let`), there's no need to instantiate an instance of the class. Use it like so:

```
graphPoints += AlarmViewController.AlarmValInt
```

Comment: I am getting an "Expected Declaration" error when I added this line in **GraphView.Swift**: `var graphPoints = [Int](); graphPoints += AlarmViewController.AlarmValInt`

Answer (score 1):

Your comment >>> I am getting an "Expected Declaration" error when I added this line in GraphView.Swift: `var graphPoints = [Int](); graphPoints += AlarmViewController.AlarmValInt`

I think you need to declare array like `var graphPoints = [Int](10)`. After declaration, you can assign your array size in your method again. I faced problem similier to this one. That worked for me. I hope it will work for your code also. :)

Comment: I edited the array declaration and left the second line unchanged but same error. Also, what do you mean by "you can assign your array size in your method again"?